# Kotlin coroutines: flatMapLatest emits nothing

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

There is the `sourceFlow` and I use `flatMapLatest` to produce new flow by value from `sourceFlow`.
And there is no value in `collect()`. This code prints nothing.

```
fun main() {

    fun createNewFlow(): MutableSharedFlow<String> = MutableSharedFlow()
    runBlocking {
        val sourceFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Int>()

        // flow for transform
        val set = mapOf(
            1 to createNewFlow(),
            2 to createNewFlow(),
            3 to createNewFlow()
        )


        launch {
            // get flow from set by number from sourceFlow
            val res = sourceFlow.flatMapLatest { set[it]!! }
            res.collect {
                println(it)
            }
        }

        launch {
            sourceFlow.emit(1)
            set[1]!!.emit("1")
            set[1]!!.emit("1")
            sourceFlow.emit(2)
            set[2]!!.emit("2")
            set[2]!!.emit("2")
        }
    }
}
```

If I change `flatMapLatest` to `flatMapConcat` I see `1` twice, it is obviously because flow from set[1] is not completed, but I'm waiting for `1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3` when I use `flatMapLatest`. What is wrong with my sample?

**UPD:**
I just added delay to get result of `println`.
So, this is really a race in the code

```
launch {
        delay(3000)
        sourceFlow.emit(1)
        set[1]!!.emit("1")
        set[1]!!.emit("1")
    }
```

Comment: This is a race in your code, you aren't guaranteed to get results either way.  The results may all be emitted before your `print` actually starts.

Comment: `delay(3000)` is an overkill, just `yield()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @louis-wasserman noted in the comments, it is a race (though not a thread-unsafe data race).

`flatMapLatest` internally `collect`s (and cancels) the sub-flows. By default, [MutableSharedFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow.html) does not replay elements before the subscriptions.

So there is a race between the two coroutines. If the first coroutine becomes a subscriber after the second coroutine calls `emit`, no value will be received. You can specify the `replay` parameter to make sure the `collect` calls receive elements before the subscription.